# Recover Certificates from FUBARed windows installation

Tags: windows, windows-xp, certificate

Can you recover personal certificates from a Windows XP install that just won't boot? I want to reinstall Windows on the PC but I want to backup everything first, including the old certificates.

Comment: I guess one method maybe to upgrade from windows xp to windows vista and try exporting it there.. may take some time but could be easier than figuring out which file to backup...

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I was able to find as far as a valid location was C:\Documents and Settings\%username%\Application Data\Microsoft\Protect{GUID}

Would like someone else to confirm if this is viable to backup from and do a viable restore.  Considering the nature of the import and export process of certs.